# simpleweatherjs js plugin doesnt update new weather temp but instead returns [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, weather-api

Hi I have tried a plugin from [simpleweatherjs](http://simpleweatherjs.com/) I followed the samples there and tried to take the [geolocation](http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/Idsaj) and [auto update](http://codepen.io/fleeting/pen/mdwlI) sample to make a geolocation that automatically updates after a few minutes the script worked fine not until it reached the interval that I have set instead it gives me [Object Object] as a result

here is the script that I have

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.simpleWeather.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    getWeather(position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude); //load weather using your lat/lng coordinates

  }); 

});
$(function(){
  getWeather();
    setInterval(getWeather, 6000);
});

function getWeather(location, woeid) {

  $.simpleWeather({
    location: location,
    woeid: woeid,
    unit: 'c',
    success: function(weather) {
    html = '<h2>'+weather.temp+'&deg;'+weather.units.temp+'</h2>';
      html += '<ul><li>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</li>';
      html += '<li class="currently">'+weather.currently+'</li></ul>';

       $("#weather").html(html);
    },
    error: function(error) {
      $("#weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
    }
  });
} 

</script>
<div id="weather"></div>
```

can someone please check my code if what I did was wrong? or am I missing something here? please help me this is driving me crazy

Comment: Change the error function to `$("#weather").html('<p>' + JSON.stringify( error ) + '</p>');` and you'll see the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `getWeather` function from the `setInterval` function, but that function expects two parameters to be passed, which you don't. If you re-arrange your code as follows, it will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getWeather();
        setInterval(getWeather, 6000);
    });

    function getWeather() {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {

            var location = (position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude);
            var woeid = undefined;

            $.simpleWeather({
                location: location,
                woeid: woeid,
                unit: 'c',
                success: function(weather) {
                    html = '<h2>' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
                    html += '<ul><li>' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</li>';
                    html += '<li class="currently">' + weather.currently + '</li></ul>';

                    $("#weather").html(html);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
<div id="weather"></div>
```

You can verify this by going to this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wdPA4/

Comment: Hi I tried your code but the problem is that it is working fine on chrome but on Firefox every 6 seconds of the setInterval it gives me  a notification from firefox asking me to share my location. The solution that I could come up is to increase my setInterval could this work? or can you suggest other options?

Comment: Well, that appears to be the default behavior of Firefox, see http://flooting.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/231083-flooting-keeps-asking-for-my-location. The only solution is that people select the "Always share location" option.

Comment: Hi I tried that option and now it wont display the plugin although in chrome it remains the same

Comment: sorry I got too excited I tried your code again on firefox.. it asks for my current location but it wont display anything

Comment: never mind this is working the issue yesterday was because of firefox ;)